# Tag synonym for tyre and tires

Tags: support, status-completed

Can we get a tag synonym made for [tyre](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tyre) and [tires](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tires). I don't know which way should be the prevalent tag, but would suggest it should be the American version. Either way, it should be consolidated.

Comment: shouldn't they both be either plural or not too - "tyres" and "tires" or "tyre" and "tire", but not a mixture...

Comment: I agree ... plural would make more sense.

Comment: Are either you familiar with British-English? Seems like a native speaker should decide that, as there are more differences than just spellings.

Comment: The problem is, they both mean the same thing. When dealing with a tag, it should be lumped together. I have no issues with it one way or the other inside the Q/A itself. When the tags are split, it makes it harder to find answers with two tags which mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I did that a while back when you first asked. I just forgot to post that I had done it. :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you kind sir.